Identifying Mitutoyo connector
Mitutoyo is using this connector in their Digimatic dial indicators. Is this "a standard" connector available from some connector manufacturer?
The connector is 10mm wide with five contacts.

I have this same question here: https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/61680/identifying-mitutoyo-connector.
If this is against some policy, please let me know.

Please add pictures of its mate (what this plug plugs into). Please measure and report the accurate pitch.

What is connector pitch and how to measure it?

I derived the pitch to be approximately 1.625 mm.

I found this Google doc page from the catalog.
Connector only, Mitutoyo 06AFM380F:
https://www.microridge.com/products/mitutoyo-905338-cable/
https://www.judgetool.com/products/microridge-mitutoyo-connection-cable-for-gages-that-use-mitutoyo-905338-cable-m/
Complete cable, Mitutoyo 905338:
https://www.amazon.com/Mitutoyo-905338-Digimatic-Connecting-Straight/dp/B002SG7PPW
https://www.grainger.com/product/MITUTOYO-Data-Output-Cable-Straight-1ZRN7

Is this "a standard" connector available from some connector manufacturer?

No. It's a custom connector.
